# How can I read UDP frames and files with MATLAB

Tags: c++, c, matlab

Hello I have a matlab code from wich i want to generate an application (`.EXE` file readable under windows)  that can receive and send  `files` and `UDP frames`.

I don't know if it's possible to modifiy my MATLAB code in order to do that (reading and sending files and UDP frames) then I will use MATLAB Compiler to generate my application `(.EXE)` ?

Otherwise I think that  I will use MATLAB Coder to convert my `matlab` code to a `C` or `C++` code so I can bring the changes that I want to my `C/C++` (I think I can do it with C) code then I will make a stand-alone application that can be installed in windows by using an other tool ? Please help me I am in trouble, thank you.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21131-tcpip-socket-communications-in-matlab & Google in general

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB has a built in [UDP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/creating-a-udp-object.html) interface.  You create a `UDP` object, use `fopen` to open it and then call methods like `fread, fscanf, fwrite, fprintf` on it.